# requestPointerLock() not working inside of Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, pointerlock

I am trying to use `requestPointerLock()` inside of a Vue.js component. If the `pointerShouldLock` data item of my component is `true`, the pointer should get locked during the `beforeUpdate()` lifecycle hook. My code looks like this:

```
beforeUpdate() {
    if (this.pointerShouldLock) {
        const gameScreen = document.getElementById('game-screen')
        requestPointerLock(gameScreen)
    }
}
```

The `requestPointerLock()` function looks like this:

```
requestPointerLock = element => {
    element.requestPointerLock =
        element.requestPointerLock || element.mozRequestPointerLock        
    element.requestPointerLock()
}
```

This technique works fine with React or vanilla JS, however when using Vue.js, the pointer does not get locked. Instead, a `pointerlockerror` event gets triggered.

I've also tried using the `updated()` lifecycle hook, but this also doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea why it's not possible to successfully request the pointer lock from inside of a Vue.js component?

Comment: That's really unfortunate reviewers told you to delete your answer... Your edit is the answer, here is the [link to specs](https://w3c.github.io/pointerlock/#x3-glossary) that sits it. I voted to undelete your answer, but you should probably repost a new one, avoiding forbidden words like *"Update"*  since this is not an update, but a real answer (and the correct one). Feel free to include citations from the specs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specifications, `requestPointerLock()` can only be triggered by a valid engagement gesture (for example a click event). Requesting pointer lock programmatically without user interaction is not possible. See the [specs](https://w3c.github.io/pointerlock/#dfn-engagement-gesture) for further information.